# How to create function edit objects in object array in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create a patch or put a function for edit values of the object array.

```
comments: [{
        body: String,
        date: Date,
        id: String

    }],
```

```
router.put('/comment/:id', (req, res) => {
    const commentbody = req.body.body
    Blog.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": req.params.id }, { $set: { comments: { body: commentbody } } }).then(result => {
            res.send('comment edited');
        })
        .catch(err => res.send(err))
})
```